# How to solve the following MappingException

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm getting the following exception:

> The number of members in the
>   conceptual type 'MyModel.Customer'
>   does not match with the number of
>   members on the object side type
>   'MyNamespace.Customer'. Make sure the
>   number of members are the same.

In the following code:

```
public CusomserService
{
    // ...

    public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        return new Repository<Customer>().All(); 
    }
}

public class Repository<T>() where T : EntityObject
{
    // ...

    public IQueryable<T> All()
    {
        return _context.CreateObjectSet<T>().AsQueryable<T>(); /* HERE THE EXCEPTION IS THROWN */
    }
}
```

The generics repository was working fine until I made some changes in my EF Model. I'm letting EF create the database (through *Generate database from Model* option).

**Where do I start?**

---

**EDIT:** I've solved it.

The problem had nothing to do with EF or my model. I had renamed the data layer project (and it's assembly name) from original_name.dll to new_name.dll. I had updated the service layer project reference to the data layer project, but the the old assembly (original_name.dll) was still in the bin directory. Deleting the old assembly from the service layer's bin directory and rebuilding the solution solved the problem.

Comment: Upvoted because your edit solved my problem. I merged in some changes to the EF Data Model, but since it was a merge I had some projects still referencing old binaries. Clean->rebuild. Solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

It seems   that Classes 'MyModel.Customer' does not match with each other 'MyNamespace.Customer'.

Try right clicking on the edmx file and selecting Run Custom Tool

or right click on edmx in solution explorer and open with xml and verify your recent changes.

Comment: I agree + In case of using T4 template run custom tool on it.

Comment: Thanks @swapneel. It turned out that the problem had nothing to do with my EF model. Still, it was a helpful answer (+1).