# The type 'Edm.Int32' of the member 'SessionId' in the conceptual side type 'Converter.Session' does not match with the type 'System

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

When I log in my simple application. It will appear this error.

**The type 'Edm.Int32' of the member 'SessionId' in the conceptual side type 'Converter.Session' does not match with the type 'System.Decimal' of the member 'SessionId' on the object side type**

Below my error line code

```
List<User> users = context.Users.ToList<User>();
```

Blow the my full code

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    InputBox("User Name", "Please enter User ID", ref UserName);

    QuestionId = 0;
    Boolean UserExsits = false;
    context = new ConversionGameDBContainer();
    List<User> users = context.Users.ToList<User>();// this is error line
    foreach (User i in users)
    {
        if (i.UserId.ToString().Trim().Equals(UserName.Trim()))
        {
            UserExsits = true;
            UserLogged = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Hello " + UserName + "!!! you are back, Enjoy the game");
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!UserExsits)
    {
        User u = new User();

        u.UserId = UserName;
        context.Users.Add(u);

        context.SaveChanges();
        MessageBox.Show("User Id " + UserName + " Created and enjoy the game");
        UserLogged = true;
    }

    ConvertorButton.Enabled = false;
    if (UserLogged)
    {
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
        session = new Session();
        session.StartTime = d;
        session.UserId = UserName;
        context.Sessions.Add(session);

        context.SaveChanges();
        context.Entry(session).GetDatabaseValues();

        SessionId = session.SessionId;
    }

    if (f == null)
    {
        f = new HistoryResult();
    }

    PlayConversionGame.UserName = UserName;
    f.Show();
    String Output = "";
    context = new ConversionGameDBContainer();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a bit old, but I stumble on it while confronted to the same error message.

Deleting the bin and object folder, then re-running the project, solved the problem for me.

Also see this question (edit part of the OP):
[How to solve the following MappingException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480593/how-to-solve-the-following-mappingexception)